# Datatable jeditable unnecessary alert box on successful update operation

Tags: jquery, datatables, jeditable

I have the same code on a standalone app and it works fine. But I am trying to achieve the same in codeigniter but this problem happens.
I am using jquery datatables and jeditables to update a field in the table. When I click the field, the select box appears and I can change the data as I wish. When the form get submitted, I see an alert box popping out with the new value that I choose. When I click ok, the field gets updated and the database too. My question is where is the alert box coming from? I had the same code on a standalone and it just works without the alert box. here is the code:

```
$('#jobs_table').dataTable({                    
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "bServerSide": true,
    "bProcessing":true,
    "sAjaxSource": "/jobs/list_all_completed",
    "sServerMethod":"POST",
    "aaSorting": [[ 0, "desc" ]]
    'fnServerData'   : function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback){
         $.ajax ({
          'dataType': 'json',
          'type'    : 'POST',
          'url'     : sSource,
          'data'    : aoData,
          'success' : fnCallback
         });
        }
}).makeEditable({
    sUpdateURL: "/jobs/invoiced_job_save",
    "aoColumns": [
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    {
    "placeholder" : "Update",
    indicator : 'saving ...',
    tooltip: 'click to select',
    data   : "{'':'Please select','No':'No','Yes':'Yes'}",
    type   : "select",
    onblur: 'submit',
    event : "click",
    style  : "inherit"
    }
    ]   
    });
```

The server side(invoiced_job_save) just echo the value.

Comment: Are you sure that you do not insert any debug code? Search "alert(" in your project, maybe you can find some clue.

Comment: Have you checked the source for `jeditable`. May be someone or you yourself had inserted `alert` there for some testing or debugging.

Comment: Thanks guys. this  function _fnShowError(errorText, action) in datatables.jeditable.js was causing this alert. Commenting out that line fixed it. Wondering why this is not triggering in the old app I already have. They both are using the exact same version.